# Visual Studio 2010 is not catching compile errors on build

Tags: visual-studio-2010, compilation

I have a web project running in Visual Studio 2010 and target .Net framework 4. When I 'Build' the solution it will tell me the build was successful even though there are (known) errors in the code. If I open a page that has an error, the compiler will then pick up on the error and underline it in blue instead of red.

Is there a setting that would drive this kind of behavior? Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: am having exactly the same problem with a .net 4 web forms app, did you get a fix for it in the end?

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple projects in your solution it is possible that one of them is not set to build. In your build output window did you see the name of the web project you are having issues with?

Also, check the build configuration manager to make sure you have it set.

[image]

Comment: All of the projects in the solution are set to build. I can watch the output window and see that it is building all of the folders in the project, but for some reason it is not picking up the errors.

Comment: Can you give an example of a line of code that you think should error, but doesn't?

Comment: Here is a link to the result of a 'Rebuild Solution': http://yfrog.com/6xsuccesszj. The compiler thinks everything is OK. However when I open a page with an error, it will detect it at that time:  http://yfrog.com/5berroro0j.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an MVC app, the view files (*.as{p,c}x) will not be compiled unless you explicitly enable it by passing /p:MvcBuildViews=true or enabling that flag in the project file for a given configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having similar (if not identical) problems with compiling an ASP.net 4.0 WebForm. I have a page that is a copy of an existing page in terms of markup, but the code-behind has not been created. As an example, the markup has an ASP:Button with a click event, but the event handler has not been declared in the codebehind yet. When I do a full Build/Rebuild/Clean etc., no errors are found. I open the page, and a compiler error is thrown. As far as I know I haven't made any changes to settings anywhere, just started doing this recently. Additionally, it appears that my break points aren't being caught anymore either. I'm not sure if the two are related, but they did start happening around the same time.