# asp.net mvc4 project compiles ok but gives the yellow screen of death

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5

looks like i'm not the only one with this issue

1. [Visual Studio 2010 is not catching compile errors on build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340382/visual-studio-2010-is-not-catching-compile-errors-on-build)
2. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vseditor/thread/423387c5-1649-4517-996a-fb6405ea7af0/

Getting a really weird error here

I created a brand new mvc4 .net 4.5 project in vs2012
Added nuget packages, added classes from a couple of test projects
changed the namespaces, get it to compile, run the project and voila get the YSOD with a message saying method... is not available on class ....

I have tried the following to no avail

- clean the project, rebuild and run debug again
- restart vs2012
- reboot machine
- apply windows update
- run vs2012 with only the project in question

It also appears that while there's no Compiler error, there's also no intellisense as well atleast on the EF model types too !

Hopefully there's some rational explanation for this !

UPDATE -
the specific error is

Compiler Error Message: CS0117: 'MySite.MyUserType' does not contain a definition for 'GetFor'

Where  GetFor() is a static method on type MyUserType, is in a partial class, both partial files are in the same project, both have the same namespace MySite etc. etc.

UPDATE 2 - 
Added a class to the project, left it to default Class1
typed some random text in class1 such as

klsjdflksj flksj flksj flksjdf lksjdf lskfjd

hit  and it gives no compilation error but a run-time YSOD instead

what gives ?

UPDATE 3 -
tried the "fix" from link #2 above but still getting the YSOD

Comment: a bit of code and the error could help

Comment: @AleTiro added to Q above

Comment: @Kumar try to add using for `MySite.MyUserType`

Comment: @webdeveloper, same result, btw all projec code is in the same namespace so it's redundant but tried it anyhow, is there a setting in webconfig which disables intellisense or fiddles with compilation ?

Answer (score 1):

By default mvc views doesn't compiles with project compilation, so 90% that you have bug in view page. Try add views compilation and you will get error on build.

```
In .csproj file:
<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
```

http://www.stefanprodan.eu/2011/05/compile-views-in-asp-net-mvc-3-with-visual-studio/

Comment: The exception that comes up is in a POCO class